# PHP's MOD autogenerates rows bootstrap & wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code in my wordpress. Is in the collection.php

This code makes rows when there are 3 posts and when there are 3 posts the  closes.

When I have 3, 6 or 9 posts works fine but the problem is when I have 4 or 5 posts because the  doesn't close and the code stays open.

Anyone can help me. I appreciate this very much.

Regards

```
$i = 0;
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();    
$i++; 
if($i%3 == 1){echo '<div class="row">'; }
     $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'attachment',
       'numberposts' => -1,
       'post_status' => null,
       'post_parent' => $post->ID
      );

      $attachments = get_posts( $args );
         if ( $attachments ) {
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
               echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
                echo '<a href="';
                echo the_permalink(); 
                echo '">';
               echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
                echo '</a>';
                echo '<h3 class="category-title"><a href="';
                echo the_permalink();
                echo '">';
                echo the_title();
                echo '</a></h3>';
               echo '</div>';


              }
         }
if($i%3 == 0){echo '</div>';}
     endwhile; endif;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($i%3 == 0){echo '</div>';}
endwhile; endif;
```

change to :

```
if($i%3 == 0){echo '</div>';}
endwhile; endif;  
if($i%3 != 0){echo '</div>';}
```

Comment: That doesn't work, it doesn't close the </div> from the "row" class.

Comment: Dear David, thanks for your reply. I need to have 3 div's inside per row. Your code only put one div per row. The original code I have posted runs fine but have one problem. When I have 4 or 5 posts, the </div> doesn't close the row. If I have 3 posts works fine but fails when i have 4, 5, 7, 8, posts

Comment: Also, I think you have to check if it is the last array element and if it so then add `</div>`